# Why can't I update has_many :through association in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My project is about an online shopping site, using Ruby on Rails to buy phones.
Now i'm trying to create Basket for Users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :baskets
  has_many :phones, :through => :baskets
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :baskets
  has_many :users , :through => :baskets
end

class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :phone
end
```

When i update like that:

```
Phone.baskets.where(user_id:1).update(name:"abc")
```

It's wrong!
I dont know why it doesn't work.

Comment: What kind of error does it give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two different things, Class vs Instance.

Phone is a class but the relationship of baskets belongs on an instance of that class.

So something like this should allow you to use the relation

```
instance_of_phone = Phone.first
instance_of_phone.baskets.where(user_id: 1).update(name: 'abc')
```

Another way is to access directly

```
Basket.find_by(user_id: 1, basket_id: 1).update(name: 'abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, as @Austio's answer pointed out, you need to use the association method on an instance of a class, not the class itself.  So: `<specific instance of Phone>.baskets` instead of `Phone.baskets`.

Secondly, if you are looking to update all of the objects of a collection with the same attribute, you need to use `update_all`.  So, let's say that `phone` is a specific Phone object.  Then you would want:

`phone.baskets.where(user_id:1).update_all(name:"abc")`

The `update` method is designed to either update the attributes of one single object, or update an array of multiple objects with an array of separate attribute hashes: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class